# Excel File Reader Script in Powershell Not Working?

Tags: excel, powershell

I wanted to read the contents of an excel file and then output them to a text file. Currently, my code only outputs the results to the console.

I tried to write code that gets the applicable columns and then loads them into an array to be written to the console later.

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $False
$PLACE = "C:\Somepath\somename.xlsx"
$OpenFile = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($PLACE)
$Workbook = $OpenFile.Worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Item(1)

# Get the values for each column
$MNumber = $Worksheet.Cells | where {$_.value2 -eq "Material-Number"} | select -First 1
$MDescription = $Worksheet.Cells | where {$_.value2 -eq "Material-Description"} | select -First 1

# Get the values for each row in Material Number 
$NumValues = @()
$NumValues = for($i=2; $MNumber.Cells.Item($i).Value2 -ne $null; $i++  ){
    $MNumber.Cells.Item($i)
}

# Get the values for each row in Material Description
$DescValues = @()
$DescValues = for($i=2; $MDescription.Cells.Item($i).Value2 -ne $null; $i++  ){
    $MDescription.Cells.Item($i)
}

$NumValues | ForEach-Object {Write-host $_.value2}
$DescValues | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.value2}
```

Nothing output to the console by the end of the process. Even though those are the exact columns and each column contains data.

Comment: [1] is excel installed on the target system? [2] has the account that is running the script _run excel at least once on that system_? [3] do you see any errors at all? [4] if you step thru the script, at what point do you NOT see the expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `match` instead of `eq` here:

`$MNumber = $Worksheet.Cells | where {$_.value2 -match "Material-Number"} | select -First 1
$MDescription = $Worksheet.Cells | where {$_.value2 -match "Material-Description"} | select -First 1`

I'm not sure if your cell has other strings within it on `$_.value2` but if it does `eq` will not work. It's trying to find the ENTIRE string it's conditioning against. Therefore, if there's other strings of data within the cell it will not pull the data.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! I was expecting match to work here.

Comment: Yeah I try to use the `match` operator in most situations. There's some senarios where `eq` may be needed, but usually it's `match`. Glad it worked for you!